# Create Executable roslisp script

Tags: ros, catkin, roslisp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using catkin ros. Now I'm trying to make a lisp script executable with "rosrun xxx".

The roslisp tutorial is kind of out of date, so I tried different approaches with information I got from different places.

Now in the CMakeList.txt, I have

```
install(PROGRAMS
  src/beckon.lisp
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```

At the head of the .lisp script, I add

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
"true" ; exec /usr/bin/env sbcl --noinform --script "$0" "$@"
```

To make it executable

My code snippet is

```
(defpackage :lisp_interpreter
(:use :roslisp :cl))
```

However, when I actually run it, I got error messages

```
Unhandled SB-KERNEL:SIMPLE-PACKAGE-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD
                                                 "main thread" RUNNING
                                                  {1002A8B3A3}>:
The name "ROSLISP" does not designate any package.
```

Besides that, the following hello world code seems to be problematic

```
(with-ros-node ("lisp_interpreter")
(sleep 1)
)
```

with error

```
; in: WITH-ROS-NODE ("lisp_interpreter")
;     ("lisp_interpreter")
; 
; caught ERROR:
;   illegal function call
; 
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     WITH-ROS-NODE
;   caught 1 ERROR condition
Unhandled SB-INT:COMPILED-PROGRAM-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD
                                                "main thread" RUNNING
                                                 {1002A8B3A3}>:
  Execution of a form compiled with errors.
Form:
  ("lisp_interpreter")    
Compile-time error:
  illegal function call
```

How to make it works?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207561/create-executable-roslisp-script/) by [firstprayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/22028/firstprayer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Small comment first: your `beckon.lisp` is actually a shell script, so at least call it `beckon.lisp.sh` or something.

But your problem has nothing to do with executables themselves I think, even if you tried your function in the lisp command line (repl) it probably wouldn't work. It seems that your *.asd file is not set up properly. You need a dependency on roslisp, it seems to not have been loaded. The setup of ROS Lisp packages is also described in the tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/roslisp/Tutorials/OrganizingFiles#Setting_up_a_new_roslisp_ROS_package

---

Originally posted by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) with karma: 311 on 2015-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1